# c++how does thread read queue of main program?

Tags: c++

There is a thread as below:

`

```
    void HighAG::startHighAG(int num)
    {
        qDebug() << " Thread start" <<  " || " << QThread::currentThread();
        while (AGstart) {
            {
                //QMutexLocker locker(&lock);
                qDebug() << "Thread running ";
           
                qDebug() << "*****Thread startHighAG::OnTick：" << this->tickQue.back().askPrice1;
                QThread::sleep(1);
                if (!AGstart) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        qDebug() << "Stopped " ;
    }
```

`

and there is fucntion recieving datas

`

```
    void HighAG::On_Tick(std::shared_ptr<QuoteInfo> quote)
    {
        tickQue.push(*quote);
        qDebug() << "startHighAG::OnTick：" << tickQue.back().askPrice1;
        emit sendTick(tickQue);
    }
```

`

In On_Tick, it print out datas no problem.
But in thread "startHighAG", it shows empty queque error.

how can the thread read the tickQue?

new in c++, Thanks for any help

Comment: You're essentially asking us to debug an interaction between two functions, but have provided no information (or code) that calls them, so no context on how they interact.   The best you'll get will be based on lucky guesses.  Follow guidance on how to provide a [mcve], otherwise nobody can help you

Comment: @Peter I thought I said 2 things work is enough, so save your teachers time :) 1. On_Tick datas no problem means this function feed data into tickQue no problem. 2. Thread shows emty queue, means thread running . just one question, how thread get the tickQue. I am new on this forum, sorry if I didnt follow the example rules. thanks for reminder, Iwill post more as I can next time.